# last element of the array gets printed first on iteration

Tags: java, iterator, set

```
import java.util.*;
class next {
public static void main( String args[] ) {
 String elements[] = { "Suhail" , "Shadow" , "Stars" };
 Set s = new HashSet( Arrays.asList( elements ) );
 Iterator i = s.iterator();
   while( i.hasNext() ) {
 System.out.println( i.next() );
   }
 }
}
```

The output that follows is :

```
Stars
Shadow
Suhail
```

Why do i get the last element printed first ? I expected the output to be `suhail , shadow , stars`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HashSet` **doesn't** guarantee **any** order. Use `LinkedHashSet` instead to preserve insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for using HashSet, in this case ArrayList would be perfect?

Do you just need an iteration?

```
for (final String string : elements) {
  System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `HashSet` to an `Arraylist` which is the common type for lists.